# Display user role with the Advanced forum module

Tags: 7, users

I use the Advanced forum and the Author pane modules.

I want to show the role the user has, as in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I looked everywhere, but I have not found a real solution.

NB: I'm not a PHP expert.

Comment: Users often have multiple roles.  Do you want to show all roles a user has or just one in the case a user has multiple roles?

Answer (score 1):

In advanced forum module edit advf-author-pane.tpl.php in your chosen forum theme and and below `print $account_name;` you'll need a similar line like `print implode(', ', $account['roles'];`. It should be wrapped in some HTML tag (span, p, ...) so you can style its display.